# SystemSoundID Volume

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using :

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)filePath, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

for playing sounds in my app.

I have an issue that when i press the volume buttons of the device in iPhone4 iPad it control the volume of the sounds, but in iPhone 3gs and iPod4 the volume buttons not control the app sound so the sounds always play in high volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to access volume within application.
 `MPVolumeView` control is used for that. Import `MediaPlayer.framework` in your project. Try to add subview of `MPVolumeView` in your `subview`. If you got some trouble while implementing this, feel free to [have a quick look for implementation](http://goo.gl/90mbf).